# How to change material progress bar fill bar to right

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, material-design, angular10

I use this code but fill bar have not change right side.

```css
.mat-progress-bar-primary .mat-progress-bar-fill .mat-progress-bar-element {
    animation: none;
    transform-origin: top right;
    transition: transform 250ms ease;
}
```

Comment: Do you want a reverse loading of progress bar?

Comment: yeah.  I want to reverse  loading of progress bar

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in a quick way by setting the direction of this `mat-progress-bar` to `rtl`. Read more about [dir at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/dir).

```html
<mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" value="60" dir="rtl"></mat-progress-bar>
```

[image]

See [this example on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gp6ktd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fprogress-bar-determinate-example.html).